# React - MUI - Autcomplete, store & load checked items

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I want to select and store some items. After reloading these values have to be already selected in the list. how i can store and load selected values, that for the next time (reloading, the stored data), the selected values will be selected in the Autocomplete list ?

```js
export default function BuzwordTags(props) {
  const tNdsProps = props.titelNdsProps.NotesDashboradProps;
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState("");

  const updates = {
    buzwords: selectedOptions,
  };

  React.useEffect(
    () => (
      setSelectedOptions(tNdsProps.expenses[0].buzwords),
      console.log("Selectet options changed", selectedOptions)
    ),
    [tNdsProps.activeNote]
  );

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        onChange={(event, value) => setSelectedOptions(value)}
        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
          <li {...props}>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.title}
          </li>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Checkboxes"
            placeholder="Favorites"
            value={selectedOptions != "" ? selectedOptions[0].title : ""}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedOptions(tNdsProps.activeNote.id, updates);
        }}
      >
        Add B-Words
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
];
```

Comment: have you tried saving the selectedOptions variable on a higher order state, for example Redux? that way the state is not tied to the specific component.

Comment: i get the selected items, but have not found out how to reload the list and compare with the selected items. That i can select new items and delete selected items